# Coefficient of function different than polynomial

Tags: equation-solving

My question arise from the problem that Mathematica can't solve the equation

$$
\text{Solve}\left[e^{a-x} (0.0299584 a+0.1 b-0.0299584 x-0.152913)-0.9 a+0.9 b+0.9 x+0.18=0.0498614 e^{-x} \left(e^a ((0.09 a-0.378) a+b (0.600833 x+0.660917)-0.54075 x-0.107925)+5.4075 \left(3.00417 e^x (-1. a+b+x+0.2)+a-b+0.8\right)\right)\land (0.1 b-0.09) e^{a-x}+0.9 (-a+b+x+0.1)=\frac{1}{2} e^{-x-2.2} \left(0.9 e^a \left(0.09 \left(a^2-4.2 a+5.41\right)-6.00833 (-0.1 (a-1) b+0.09 a-0.19)\right)+5.4075 \left(e^{x+1.1} (-a+b+x+0.1)+0.9 (a-b+0.8)\right)\right),\{a,b\}\right]
$$

I was thinking about extracting coefficients of $\exp{x}$ of the LHS of the first equation and then compare it with the same coefficient on the RHS. Then perform the same operation, but with the coefficient of $x\exp{x}$ and so on?
How to do it?

Comment: Welcome to _Mathematica_.SE. You will attract more attention to your question if edited the LaTeX expression into plain text _Mathematica_ code that people can copy and paste into _Mathematica_ and experiment with.

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution, but you could try Expand and Collect. Example:

```mathematica
lhs = a x E^(x - a) + Exp[x] (x - 1)^2 + 5/Exp[-x];
Collect[Expand[lhs], {x^2*Exp[x], x*Exp[x], Exp[x]}]
```

output

```
6 E^x + E^x (-2 + a E^-a) x + E^x x^2
```

note:

- the order of the second argument of Collect
- different input style of E^ and Exp[] doesn't matter here, but sometimes exact input form matters for Collect (check the documentation of Collect)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help